# EmberJS Handelbars compiler not working

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to compile a template myself in a Ember View. (which I know isn't the best solution). When I use the standard Handlebars.compile everything works ok, but I want to use the EmberJS helpers (e.g. linkTo), but for some strange reason this isn't working. Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

This is working fine:

```
var menuitem = Handlebars.compile("<li>{{label}}</li>");
this.menu.prepend( menuitem( {label:"Homepage"} ) );
```

This isn't:

```
var menuitem = Ember.Handlebars.compile("<li>{{label}}</li>");
this.menu.prepend( menuitem( {label:"Homepage"} ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the full Handlebars library or just the runtime version of it. Usually Ember comes with just the handlebars-runtime.js. Make sure you have full version. Handlebars.Compile is not included in the runtime version.